# How to use split.item in SQL, spliting cols by commas

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I'm getting the error:

> "The multi-part identifier "split.item" could not be bound."

Pretty much I'm going to make a third table with each individual person this is just an example:

```
SELECT 
      split.item as memberID 
FROM 
     tics T 
  JOIN
     mem M
  ON
     m.memberId = split.item
  CROSS APPLY 
     dbo.Splitstring(t.Resources,',') AS split
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have the join in wrong order, you can't refer to something that comes later in the SQL, in this case "m.memberId = split.item" since split is the next item you're adding there. The correct way to do this is:

```
SELECT 
  split.item as memberID 
FROM 
  tics T 
  CROSS APPLY dbo.Splitstring(t.Resources,',') AS split
  JOIN mem M ON m.memberId = split.item
```